# UWP SDK and .net framework

Tags: c#, uwp, dji-sdk, visa

I am working on a program where I need to be able to interface with both a DJI drone and a RIGOL spectrum analyzer. The DJI drone uses a UWP SDK while the spectrum analyzer I believe only uses the VISA.NET library which I believe is incompatible with UWP applications. Do you guys know how I might go about bridging the two together in one program?

https://github.com/dji-sdk/Windows-SDK

https://www.rohde-schwarz.com/us/applications/r-s-visa-application-note_56280-148812.html

Comment: To be clear I already have an existing UWP program and I want to communicate with the spec analyzer. It uses SCPI to communicate

Comment: Ok I see I can use Desktop Extension like in this article: https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/     What I dont understand is how to add a .net framework project to my solution in VS. If I go to add a new project only .net core console applications are availible.

Comment: You can use  `Ivi.Visa.Interop`